# Using DevOps Release REST API to determine time for release to complete

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm using the DevOps REST API here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0

I have a specific release pipeline that I want to monitor for performance, I'd like to be able to query the pipeline to determine how long it's been taking to complete over the last n runs.  then I can take that data and use it to determine if there's been any degradation in performance over time.

Is it possible to determine this info using the existing APIs? The API above seems to only talk about release start time, from playing around with the various options I haven't been able to get completion time from it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very easy to find but the following link returns the data you need: 
https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/Utopia-Demo/Utopia/_apis/release/releases/1

```
 "releaseDeployPhases": [
                        {
                           ...
                            "deploymentJobs": [
                                {
                                    "job": {
                                        ...
                                        "dateStarted": "2019-01-23T14:40:59.603Z",
                                        "dateEnded": "2019-01-23T14:42:49.863Z",
                                        "startTime": "2019-01-23T14:40:59.603Z",
                                        "finishTime": "2019-01-23T14:42:49.863Z",
                                        ...
                                    },
```

Here is a start and end time on the job that you can use to calculate the job length.

Comment: Interesting, none of the release builds in my entire project have that attribute.

Comment: OK, found it.  The reason I wasn't seeing it before: I was using the "List" API to get the top 50 Releases for a given pipeline.  If I switched to using the Get Release API I also get a Release object back, but it contains more information than the List API.  So for my needs, I'll probably have to get a list first, then take the release IDs and query individually.

Comment: Yeah, that's the process. You can page the List API to get all release IDs and then get the details for individual releases.